# On boot `^[[6~` is printed

Tags: keyboard

When I boot Ubuntu, Arch Linux or so, the string `^[[6~` is printed very often. I suspect that a key is stuck, but I don’t know which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `^[[6~` is generated by Page Down key.

You can check it at the command-line in `bash` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>.